# The custom layout isn't loading automatically

Tags: ihp

I have created a custom layout in Layout.hs. This is applied to a reporting page that has a different styling (CSS) and JS from the rest of the application.

The report page is accessed via link in the application.

The problem is that when landing on the report page the custom layout (CSS and JS) isn't applied automatically. It only kicks in after a manual refresh.

Any ideas how to fix this?